# How can I aggregate data fields into the same row with standard SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have a data frame that looks as follows:

| ID | Quarter | Skill | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Q1 | Excel | Technical |
| A | Q1 | SQL | Technical |
| A | Q2 | Python | Technical |
| A | Q2 | R | Technical |
| B | Q1 | Java | Technical |
| B | Q1 | Presentation | Soft Skill |
| B | Q1 | Leadership | Soft Skill |
| B | Q2 | Excel | Technical |

I would like to aggregate certain rows of data (in this example, "Skill" and "Type") while leaving others separated (in this example, "Quarter"), such that my goal result would look something like this:

| ID | Quarter | Skill | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Q1 | Excel, SQL | Technical, Technical |
| A | Q2 | Python, R | Technical, Technical |
| B | Q1 | Java | Technical |
| B | Q1 | Presentation, Leadership | Soft Skill, Soft Skill |
| B | Q2 | Excel | Technical |

I have tried to use the "arrayagg()" function to accomplish this, but can't seem to get the correct result, as my output does not aggregate my results on the same line as expected.

Query Used:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Quarter, array_agg(DISTINCT Skill) Skill, array_agg(DISTINCT Type) Type
FROM table1
GROUP BY ID, Quarter, Skill, Type
```

Comment: I have removed the <ansi> tag, since neither the question nor the answer are ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: You very rarely need to combine GROUP BY with SELECT DISTINCT. It just raises a lot of eyebrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the aggregation you're looking for, you need to slightly adjust your SQL query. The issue with your current approach is that you're grouping by both Skill and Type columns, which prevents aggregation across these dimensions. Instead, you want to group only by ID and Quarter, and then aggregate Skill and Type within these groups.

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    Quarter, 
    array_agg(Skill) AS Skills, 
    array_agg(Type) AS Types
FROM table1
GROUP BY ID, Quarter
```

Comment: Did you create this answer with [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)?